# Java : how to add columns to dataframe based on a list of objects

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, iterator

I have to add columns to my dataframe and columns= List so i have to iterate over this list of objects:

```
columns=[
{val1="A",val2="num1"},
{val1="B",val2="num2"},
{val1="C",val2="num3"},
{val1="D",val2="num4"}
]
```

**mydataframe**

```
 |nom     |prenom   | age |
 |arnauld | simpson | 43  |
```

**expected result is:**

```
 |nom     |prenom   | age | A   | B  | C  | D  |
 |arnauld | simpson | 43  |num1 |num2|num3|num4|
```

what i tried is :

```
Iterator<Myclass> iterator = cols.iterator();
Dataset<Row> result=myDf;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {

  Myclass res = iterator.next();

  String val1= res.getVal1();
  String val2= res.getVal2();
 

  result = myDf.withColumn(val1, expr(val2));
  result.show();

}
```

but i don't have the result expected, i only have the last object (val1="D",val2="num4").
How can i obtain my expected result please?

Comment: You can create another data frame from the iterator object and join with main data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result = myDf.withColumn(val1, expr(val2));`

should be

`result = result.withColumn(val1, expr(val2));`

Otherwise you are discarding the `result` in each iteration.

```
Iterator<Myclass> iterator = cols.iterator();
Dataset<Row> result=myDf;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {

  Myclass res = iterator.next();

  String val1= res.getVal1();
  String val2= res.getVal2();
 

  result = result.withColumn(val1, expr(val2));
  result.show();

}
```